# Plot binary pattern in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a dataset regarding to the sleeping pattern of people that looks like:

```
                               Time
                 _________________________________________

Sub     Day      21:01    21:02   21:03   ...   ... 06:00
___    _____     _____    _____   _____             _____

 1      1        1        1        0                0
 1      2        1        1        0                0
 1      3        0        1        0                0
 1      4        0        1        0                0
 2      1        1        2        0                0
 2      2        1        2        0                0
 3      1        1        2        1                0
 ...
 ...

 10     1        1        1        0                0  
 10     2        1        1        0                0
 10     3        0        1        0                0
```

Each subject (Sub column) is assessed for different days (Day column) from 21:01 PM to 06:00AM with a sample rate of 1 minute.

The "ones" and "zeros" in the Time columns mean "sleep" and "awake", respectively.

I would like to produce a plot in Matlab like the following:

[image]

Since I have different days for each patient I would like also to have different grades of blue (or another color) representing the probability that each patient is sleeping at that minute. i.e. if a patient in all the assessed days at 21:01 PM slept this "cell" should have the darkest color possible.

My data could be represented with the following matrix.
The first 2 columns are the subjects (only 2 subjects) and the days, the other 100 are 100 assessed minutes.

```
data=[1,1,round(rand(1,100));...
  1,2,round(rand(1,100));...
  1,3,round(rand(1,100));...
  2,1,round(rand(1,100));...
  2,2,round(rand(1,100));...
  2,3,round(rand(1,100));...
  2,4,round(rand(1,100))];
```

Comment: Use `imshow` (or `imagesc` if you don't have the image processing toolbox) with your array of zeros/ones (or probabilities)

Comment: Instead of a binary table you can put the probabilities (from 0 to 1) of that patient to be sleeping in each cell.
Then you can use `plot` with brackets [] to convert each probability value to a intensity color.

Comment: Hi Jonas  I have added an exemple of data..

Comment: How can I select a gray scale using imagesc and the probabilities? at the moment I have random colors..

Comment: @gabboshow make your input data into an RGB triple. For example, `x = round(rand(10,10)); imagesc(x);` gives you a blue and yellow display, but a full RGB matrix will give you black and white. e.g. `x = repmat(x,1,1,3); imagesc(x)`.

Comment: @gabboshow simply type `colormap gray` and it will convert it to grayscale.